# Firehose not pushing data into s3 through Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to invoke kinesis through my lambda function . Here is my code

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode:200,
        Name:event.Name,
        Value:event.Value
    };
const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'kinesis-fh-pika', 
  Record: { Data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(response)) }
};

firehose.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);
});
};
```

Here is my Events

```
{
  "Name": "sara",
  "Value": 10
}
```

I am not getting any error in the lambda. It is always showing the reponse as `null`. I even tried enabling logs but didnt find any weird behaviour .

Am i missing anything ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can able to resolve my question . All i am missing is an `callback` call . It seems the putRecord is only happening when it is getting some response callback.Here is the working code

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode:200,
        Name:event.Name,
        Value:event.Value
    };
const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'kinesis-fh-pika', 
  Record: { Data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(response)) }
};

firehose.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);
});
callback(null,"success");
};
```

Comment: callback is not defined. this => exports.handler = async (event) needs to be => exports.handler = async (event, context, callback)

Comment: Thanks @ChadElias for pointing that . It is a bad copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

it's returning 'null' because your Lambda function is not returning anything.

try this

```
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode:200,
        Name:event.Name,
        Value:event.Value
    };
const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'kinesis-fh-pika', 
  Record: { Data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(response)) }
};

firehose.putRecord(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } // an error occurred
  else {
    console.log(data);
  }
 return response;
});
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Chad Elias. Usually when you Put a record in firehose it will give you a `RecordId`. I want that to be shown in my lambda output instead of null, because once i received that then it means the data is pushed to S3.

Comment: Sry it doesn't for me when i used your code . But i upvoted it. Thanks